# Finding Highest Order 1 in a Java Primitive

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need to find the highest order 1 in some longs, ints, and shorts in Java. For example, if I had a char that looked like `00110101`, I need a method that will return 2 (index of highest order 1).

Now, I know that you can do this using a for loop like:

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    if((x & 1<<i) != 0) return i;
return -1;
```

but this is way slower than what I want to do. I know modern CPUs have instructions that do this on chip, so I want to know how I can make a call to that rather than having an explicit loop.

EDIT: Bonus points if you can just return the indices of all of the ones in the primitive.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running on a big endian machine?

Comment: I was under the impression that Java handled endianess in its own way in the JVM, but assuming it doesn't, I will be using an Intel C2D, so little endian.

Comment: Running your code, I get 0, not 2.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what are you trying to solve that can only be solved using these kind of bit-hacks?

Comment: @unknown, my code is backward, it finds the lowest order bit. whether its high or low doesn't really matter.

@Bart K, I am writing a bitboard for chess. I would love to give up Java and do it in C, but I have a lot of ugly network code that I don't want to have to rewrite in C.

Comment: If you are more comfortable doing bit manipulation in C, why not use JNI? Also, if you are trying to get all 'on' indeces, perhaps your algorithm may not be benefiting from using a bit field... Is a bit field really the best data structure for what you are doing?

Comment: I wasn't aware the bit manipulation was that different in Java.  What are you trying to do that you would easily do in C?

Comment: @twolfe18 an approach you might want to try is to write your app in java. When it runs as it should, you optimize, possibly by writing some of the lower level stuff in C using JNI, as Kevin Day suggested. Going offtopic; Robert Hyatt has written several nice articles on bitboard chess.

Comment: @unknown, that is pretty much what i am planning to do. right now i have a method to find the highest order 1, and i might switch it out with JNI later.

Comment: Note: the JNI overhead will more than eat up any microgains you get from this single C operation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i) + 1`

That method uses a nice divide-and-conquer approach, copied here for your review:

```
public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-6
    if (i == 0)
        return 32;
    int n = 1;
    if (i >>> 16 == 0) { n += 16; i <<= 16; }
    if (i >>> 24 == 0) { n +=  8; i <<=  8; }
    if (i >>> 28 == 0) { n +=  4; i <<=  4; }
    if (i >>> 30 == 0) { n +=  2; i <<=  2; }
    n -= i >>> 31;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm is elegant, but shifting is horribly slow AFAIK.

Comment: Better to shift 8 times (worst case), than 32, like generalizing the loop from the question would. (And that is assuming the JIT-Compiler unrolls the loop, otherwise the branch overhead would dominate.

Comment: Is there a reference for shifting being "horribly slow" in Java?  I've never heard that.

Comment: Shifts should not be any slower in Java. Java has the `iushr` (unsigned shift right) bytecode instruction `0x7c`, with 2 arguments. This should translate 1:1 to a `SHR` assembly instruction on any x86 machine.

Comment: Shifts aren't slow, and anyway, the jit likely recognizes numberOfLeadingZeros and turns it into a small number of instructions that do the scan in hardware.

Answer (score 3):

The page "[Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)" contains lots of bit hacks. One is how to find the [index of the highest order bit](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious).

Comment: I used to use these algorithms in my Java code, but most of them have been added to the platform API in the last few years.

Comment: However the de Bruijn sequence method is still marginally faster than the divide-and-conquer method used in the built-in `numberOfLeadingZeros` and `numberOfTrailingZeros`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is faster. But it has no loop.

```
if(i==0) return -1;

highest=0;
if (i & 0xffff0000)
{
   highest+=16;
   i>>=16;
}
if (i & 0xff00)
{
   highest+=8;
   i>>=8;
}
if (i & 0xf0)
{
   highest+=4;
   i>>=4;
}
if (i & 0xC)
{
   highest+=2;
   i>>=2;
}
if (i & 0x2)
{
   highest+=1;
}

return highest;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about hitting a CPU instruction, but I do know that this will be a lot faster if you unroll the loop and use explicit bit masking.

Also, a char is not 8 bits...  I think you might have meant a byte.

Comment: I was thinking of C style char's (they're 8 bits right?...). Are Java's chars are 2 bytes for unicode support?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the Pentium and friends don't have an instruction ready-made for this. So the thing to do is to use a decent algorithm.

The key to getting your answer quickly is to use a binary search. You're looking at a `long` with 64 bits? 6 comparisons will give you your highest bit, every time.

The code works out to a big ugly tree of 64 if statements, but only a fraction of those will ever be executed, so runtime is good.

If you need sample code, I can do that. But I'd rather not.

Comment: It need not be expressed using a tree, see my answer.

Comment: As I commented, I like the elegance of the code but I doubt its performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Java being compiled into platform-independent bytecode, you cannot expect support for CPU instructions. Otherwise your code or Integer.highestOneBit() should be as fast as it gets.

Comment: well, i agree in principle, but i think java does do some things in platform dependent ways (for efficiency), but they fall back on a java implementation if the platform is not cooperative. i was hoping this was one of them...

Comment: Of course the JVMs are platform-specific, but for your case the JIT compiler would have to detect your true intention from the bytecode, which may be difficult. But if speed is of the essence, you might consider using platform-independent assembler, i.e. a C library and JNI.